# OS X Yosemite resolution "jump" when logging in

Tags: macos, login, resolution

When I start my MacBook Pro Retina, the resolution is the non-scaled option. But on my user account, I have selected the 1680x1050 scaled option. This means that when i login the resolution "jumps/flashes" from non scaled to scaled.

Is there a way to make the login screen the same resolution or is there another solution?

Comment: Oh my... I've had the exact same problem for like 1 month and just decided to post about it here this morning. Only difference is, that my resolution at the login screen is 1024x768, so it looks pretty bad to be honest...

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the Option-Command-P-R keys immediately after powering on. This will reset the login screen resolution

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a non-Retina Mac and fixed it by changing the resolution for the root user, then restarting. It seems the root user sets the resolution for the login screen (like how it controls the language and input source).

Comment: How does one change the resolution for a root user?

Comment: @Argo You may need to enable the root user first if you haven't used it before: http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT1528

Comment: I just tried it and the resolution is now good on the login screen. But when i login on my user account the screen still jumps. Its is almost like it thinks my account wants the non scaled but then after a second realises that i want the scaled, very strange.